# "Saving audio to .....@gmail.com" toast when using RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH

Tags: android, audio

I am using the RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH to capture audio using the following code:

```
public void promptSpeechInput() {
        if (checkAudioPermission()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak Your Query Now");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } else {
            showShortSnackBar("Record Permission Required");
        }
    }
```

and I have implemented the onActivityResult as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = data
                            .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    String userQuery = result.get(0);
                    addMessage(false, "Query: \n" + userQuery);
                    txtSpeechInput.setText(userQuery);
                }
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Everything works fine except I get an annoying toast saying:
**"Saving audio to .....@gmail.com"** 
How can I get rid of this toast message?